# Current flowing through a closed conducting loop in a time-dependent magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, maxwell-equations

Consider a closed conducting loop (e.g., a circular wire) in a time-dependent magnetic field. Assume that the resistance per unit length of the wire is $r$ and that its total length is $L$.

If the quantity
$$
   \frac{dB}{dt}
$$
is known, is it possible to compute the current $I$ flowing in the circular loop?

From Maxwell equations, we know that
$$
   \nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}
$$
Moreover, since a potential $V$ cannot be introduced, we cannot use the simple Ohm's law
$$
   \Delta V =I (rL)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [Faraday's Law of Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction). The electric field along the circular wire is
$$\int_{\partial C}\bf{E}\cdot d\bf {r}= \int\int_{C} \frac{\partial \bf{B}}{\partial t} \cdot d\bf{A} , $$
where $\bf{E}$ is the electric field and $C$ is the disk enclosed by the loop of wire, and ${\partial C}$ is the circular wire. Then one can use [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) to relate the current to the electric field via the conductivity $\sigma$
$$\bf{J} = \sigma \bf{E},$$

where $\bf{J}$ is the induced current.

Generally, the conductivity is related to the resistivity reciprocally
$$\sigma = \frac{1}{\rho}.$$